# UPS cord has back-flowing current in it. What to do?

Tags: inverter, ups, backup

If the UPS is switched on and it's unplugged from the wall socket, then there's some current in the plug pins as per my neon line tester. It's a three pin plug. The earth pin has no current but both the neutral and phase pins have some current flowing through. I don't know how much and I don't have the tools to measure that.

If I plug the UPS into the wall socket partially so that I can reach the partly exposed pins with my tester, and I keep the switch of the socket off, then both the pins seem to be getting drained as the tester doesn't light up.

Now I want to get a home inverter powering this socket since the small UPS doesn't cut it for my PC. My theory is, in the event of a power cut, the home inverter will keep powering this socket and the UPS should keep running as if it was getting mains supply. But now I'm worried if the UPS will send current back to the inverter and hence damage it in the process.

The reason why I'm not using the home inverter directly as a backup for my PC is that it's slow and its power output is likely not as clean as my APC UPS's.

My first question is: Why is the UPS sending current back through its cord?

My second question is: Is it safe to have the socket on a home inverter backup and then plugging a UPS into it, essentially daisy chaining two backup devices?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the first half is caused by a fundamental (read: 9th/8th grade physics) misconception about current and voltage, and the second is just a device usage question, and these are off-topic here.

Comment: the answer to your previous question already explains why your tester glows, so hm. Not really unanswered, either.

Comment: Okay I'm not sure which misconception you're referring to so could you just treat me like a child and clarify? Also, what is the correct topic for this question then? Maybe I can get some answers there.

Comment: You already have an answer! In your previous question, you were explained why your tester glows. In this question, Justme explains whether something is wrong. You need not ask somewhere else!

Comment: Re misconception: you can't "push" current into an open. current flows in closed loops, so that's the fundamental misconception. Note that this site is for electrical engineering questions, so we have to expect a relatively solid basis in fundamentals.

Answer (score 2):

Your UPS is likely fine and does not leak much current. You likely don't need to do anything. If in doubt, provide a service  manual with schematics for analysis.

You can also try your neon tester to laptop and mobile phone chargers, TVs and other two-prong consumer appliances for possibly fun results.

Comment: Okay so do all UPS leak current? Sorry I don't know much about electricity and electronics. I couldn't find a service manual, but here's the product link: https://www.apc.com/in/en/product/BX1100C-IN/apc-backups-1100va-230v-without-auto-shutdown-software-5-india-outlets-1-surge/

Comment: @OjasviSrivastava if you're still thinking about "leaking current" then you haven't read or understood the answer to your previous question.